# How to enable enhanced e-commerce tracking on a website built with NuxtJS?

Tags: google-tag-manager, enhanced-ecommerce

I have a website built with NuxtJS. Although I've been able to track events on the website, I'm facing difficulty in enabling enhanced e-commerce tracking on my website.

Nuxt doesn't allow us to add code directly to  section of a page/pages.

The website is [www.mounty.co](http://www.mounty.co) if it helps.

Comment: Sorry this hasn't gotten any answers, but I'm not sure anybody here has experience with NuxtJS.   It sounds like a pretty poor framework if you can't add code where you need it.

Comment: I'm starting to think the same.